# rename table column with metavariable

Tags: r, rename

I have a dataset named bridge with columns: agg, col, FACTOR. All are character values
I have a variable named var which is character but contain the name of a dimension that is used in another table.
here for example var <- "accounting_entry"
I want to rename the column "col" of my bridge table to accounting_entry.
I try this

```
 bridge <- bridge %>% 
   dplyr::rename(!!as.symbol(var) = col)
```

but i get the error message

```
Error: object 'ACCOUNTING_ENTRY' not found
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Could you advice please.
thanks

Comment: have you checked by running: `rlang::last_error()`? What does this show?

Comment: > rlang::last_error()
<error/rlang_error>
object 'ACCOUNTING_ENTRY' not found
Backtrace:
  2. dplyr::rename(., !!as.symbol(var) == col)
 29. tidyselect:::h(simpleError(msg, call))
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see the full context.
> rlang::last_trace()
<error/rlang_error>
object 'ACCOUNTING_ENTRY' not found
Backtrace:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using glue library

```
library(glue)
bridge <- bridge %>% 
  dplyr::rename("{var}":=col)
bridge
```

Also, in plain vanilla R, you can do this:

```
names(bridge)[names(bridge) == "col"] <- var
```